# Get column permissions on table for specified user

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have database (mssql) and some tables.
In microsoft SQL management studio I set some column permissions on one table for update (deny) for specified db user.
It works.

User can not update columns with deny permissions. He give error inform about some columns have permissions, for example:
The UPDATE permission was denied on the column 'name' of the object 'User', database 'AL', schema 'dbo'.

What I plan to do is, show table in datagrid, get column with restriction (permissions) and set them readonly. So user will not change them and update pass without errors.

My question is, how I get list (array) of this columns by c# in my code?

Edit 1)
I found this command:

```
SELECT T.TABLE_TYPE AS OBJECT_TYPE, T.TABLE_SCHEMA AS [SCHEMA_NAME], T.TABLE_NAME AS [OBJECT_NAME], NULLIF(P.subentity_name, '') as COLUMN_NAME, P.PERMISSION_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
CROSS APPLY fn_my_permissions(T.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + T.TABLE_NAME, 'OBJECT') P
WHERE T.TABLE_NAME = 'tabel_name'
ORDER BY OBJECT_TYPE, [SCHEMA_NAME], [OBJECT_NAME], COLUMN_NAME, P.PERMISSION_NAME
```

And if I see result, if I take, which column have only SELECT permission, maybe I have what I need.

Edit 2)
No Entity Framework, it is not possible

Comment: How did you set up your database? Entity Framework, code first? Are you writing your queries in 'pain' sql? More information needed to answer this question.

Comment: Ehem ... did not meant to write "'pain' sql" -> plain sql. Freudian slip ;)